# Load json file dynamically - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

please check this:

```
    var scripts = {};

require = function(src){
    var id = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

    $.ajax({
        url: src + '.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
                    async: false,
        success : function(data){
            scripts[id] = data;
        }
    });

    return scripts[id];
}
```

return undefined :/ What is the problem!? i don't know...

EDIT! 'async : false' and run!

Comment: Of course we know what JSON is. The error here has to be on the server side. Is youe `src` valid?

Comment: Try to use XMLHttpRequest object instead of jquery. It'll block.

Answer (score 3):

It is because $.ajax is asynchronous in your call.

```
return scripts[id];
```

The above line is executed even before the `success` callback is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

it is a asynchronous call. scripts is empty when you return.

to verify the cause,

```
window.scripts = {};

require = function(src){
var id = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

$.ajax({
    url: src + '.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success : function(data){
        window.scripts[id] = data;
        alert(window.scripts)
    }
});

//return scripts[id];
```

}

after alert, see the value of window.scripts

Answer (score 0):

its async issue .. Ajax call is called asynchrnously.

```
return scripts[id];
```

is executed before ajax call return.s

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the call is asynchronous. This means that your method is returning before the call is finished.

Instead of returning the scripts[id] try this instead:

```
require = function(src){
    var id = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

    $.ajax({
        url: src + '.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success : function(data){
            scripts[id] = data;
            DoStuff(scripts[id]);
        }
    });
}

DoStuff(data) {
    // do whatever it is you were going to do after the return.
}
```